# ModelState.IsValid does it work with ajax call ?

Tags: ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

the model :

```
public class ChangePasswordModel
{
    //User profile key
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Enter Current Password ")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Enter a New Password ")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and no longer then {1} characters long.")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Re-enter a New Password ")]
    [MustBeValidator(MustBeValidator.Condition.EqualTo, "newpassword", ErrorMessage = "Please, confirm password")]
    public string ReNewPassword { get; set; } 
}
```

ajax call to security apicontroller :

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel change)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

the problem is, even when the "NewPassword" diff from "ReNewPassword" I get ModelState.IsValid = true

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `MustBeValidator` is but you may try using the standard attribute for that in ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Re-enter a New Password ")]
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "Please, confirm password")]
public string ReNewPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: well your answer solved me different problem of client validation. but still ajax calls the modelstate is always valid ,do you know why ?

Comment: No, I don't know why without seeing your full code (Model, Contoller, View and javascript sending the AJAX request). This should normally work.